# Error with TNSPlayer PlayFromUrl: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"

Tags: nativescript

My previously working native script audio player no longer works. Our audio streams no longer play, the error callback refers to the player as 'undefined' and we get this longwinded error message.

> CONSOLE LOG file:///app/home/home-view-model.js:166:28: error message:
>   Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://46.28.53.118:7095/live,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://46.28.53.118:7095/live}

I have not been able to get the full console output from TNSPlayer, so I can't see what it's trying to do under the hood.If you can't help me fix this error at least help me get the full printout.

This change came about from something completely outside my control. I made no changes and suddenly TNSPlayer stopped working.

```
this.player = new TNSPlayer();

this.player.playFromUrl({
         audioFile: station.streamURL,
         loop: false,
         completeCallback: (args: any) => {
            console.log('complete callback,' args);
            console.log(args);
         },
         errorCallback: (args: any) => {
            console.log("reference back to player:", args.player);
            console.log('error message: ', args.error);
            console.log(args.extra); // Android only.
)}.then(() => {
         console.log('Audio now streaming.', this.player.isAudioPlaying());
         that.setBusy(false, page);
         that.player.volume = that.muted ? 0 : that.volume;
         that.currentlyPlaying = true;

         if (that.pendingArtwork == null) {
            const placeholderImg = applicationSettings.getString('theme', 'default') == 'blue' ? 'blue' : 'default';
            that.set('trackArtwork', `~/images/missing-${placeholderImg}.png`);
            let pendingStationName = that.currentStationName;
            setTimeout(() => {
               if (pendingStationName == that.currentStationName && that.pendingArtwork == null) {
                  that.set('trackArtwork', `~/images/stationArtwork/${shortCode}.png`);
               }
            }, 3000);
         } else {
            that.set('trackArtwork', that.pendingArtwork);
         }
         console.log('this player is playing, and its name is ', this.player);
         clearInterval(that.loadingDots);
         that.set('trackText', that.pendingTitle);
});
```

It should simply start playing the stream associated with the URL. Instead the whole thing fails.

Comment: layout and error on blockquote

Comment: Is it a issue only with iOS?

Comment: @Manoj yes, our Android version does not experience this problem.

Comment: Have you whitelisted this domain / ip on your app? You would add this to `info.plist` if you want to allow HTTP communication in your app, `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>`

Comment: @Manoj which info.plist?  A cursory search of the app directory reveals a ton of files by that name.

Comment: The only `info.plist` in your `App_Resources/iOS` directory.